# My Tkinter Files wont open after 3 tries. Please Assist me

Tags: python, tkinter

Basically I created two Tkinter files with buttons. When I click on one button it should take me to the other file and when I click a button the other file it should take me back. However, it's not working after 3 tries. Please help me find the solution for this. For more detailed question watch this video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ma_-szEf4JBbxwFgiSS5GrkIFrWI3Mog/view

Here is my code also:

```
File 1: 
from tkinter import *
root.title("Hello This is file 1")
root.geometry("600x600")

def goToFileTwo():
    root.destroy()
    import file2

button = Button(text="Click here to go to file 2", command=goToFileTwo)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

```
File 2: 
from tkinter import *
root.title("Hello This is file 2")
root.geometry("600x600")

def goToFileOne():
    root.destroy()
    import file1

button = Button(text="Click here to go to file 1", command=goToFileOne)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Please help me find a solution.

Comment: `import` statement will import the module once.  So first calling `goToFileTwo()` will import `file2`, then calling `goToFileOne()` will import `file1`.  However when `goToFileTwo()` is called again, `file1` will not be imported again.  You need to put the required code in each file in a function and call that function  instead.

Comment: You would never see this method of opening another GUI in professional code. import is not intended to be used to call code in another file, you should use function calls to do this instead. Personally, I'd have the main window as the Tk root and for any subsequent windows, create these as TopLevel windows whilst hiding/withdrawing the root window

Answer (score 1):

In the file1 and file2  you just add the below code, this will delete your imported module from system cache

```
del sys.modules["your_module_name"]
```

please don't forget to import sys module also

so your full code of file1 will be

```
from tkinter import *
import sys
root=Tk()
root.title("Hello This is file 1")
root.geometry("600x600")
try:
   del sys.modules["file2"]
except:
       None
def goToFileTwo():
    root.destroy()
    import file2
button = Button(text="Click here to go to file 2", command=goToFileTwo)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```